# Delaying While Loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="" id = "content2">Click Here</a>
<body>
</html>
```

I am using the following code to check the href attribute of the anchor tag and if it is blank I want to show alert for now. But when I write the code of javaScript in web browser console my complete system ends up unresponsive for quite some time. I might be doing something wrong. Can someone explain me what?

```
var a = document.getElementById("content2").getAttribute("href");

let i = 0;
while(a.trim().length < 1)
{
     task(i);
}

function task(i) { 
  setTimeout(function() { 
      alert(i); 
  }, 1000 * 10); 
}
```

Comment: Why is the idea behind tracking changes over a href?, using while is a no no because it blocks the code execution (is a sync function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timeout call seems to be within a while loop which gets called a ton of times. It should be

```js
var a = document.getElementById("content2").getAttribute("href");

let i = 0;

if (a.trim().length < 1) {
  task(i);
}

function task(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert(i);
    if (a.trim().length < 1) {
      task(++i);
    }
  }, 1000 * 10);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<a href="" id = "content2">Click Here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This runs your loop after each attempt where a.trim().length < 1

Answer (score 0):

You need change `while` loop to `if` condition, the `while` loop have never ended.

```js
var a = document.getElementById("content2").getAttribute("href");

let i = 0;
if(a.trim().length < 1)
{
     task(i);
}

function task(i) { 
  setTimeout(function() { 
      alert(i); 
  }, 1000 * 10); 
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<a href="" id = "content2">Click Here</a>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: But replacing if in place of while will execute the code only once. I want to execute the code every second not just once

Comment: but you need change condition of while loop? do you want to loop until what